# How to implement Stack Overflow's "are you a human" feature?

Tags: discussion

On this site if you do too many clicks or post comments too fast or something like that you get redirected to the "Are you a human" screen. Does anybody know how the developers of this site did this, or how to do something similar?

Comment: Hey people, this doesn't belong on Meta! This is about verifying someone is human. They are just using SO as an example

Comment: @Earlz: That's not what the original question said, especially given the question title.

Comment: This type of feature is known as annoying.

Comment: Was about to add this on SO before it got migrated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/captcha

Comment: And how do we get this migrated *back* to SO? This *is* a programming question, but just using SO as an example as per @earlz

Comment: @Jon Seigel. I believe the OP just didn't know how to properly phrase his question. I got from it that he was wanting to know how to implement Stack Overflow's feature. Not discuss it on Meta..

Comment: @Rob: I don't see the point... either it belongs here to find out how it was done specifically on SO, or it's a duplicate of another question.

Comment: @Jon, I guess we'll have to agree to disagree then, as I just plain think it's a valid question for SO. Would it be "migrated to experts-exchange" if someone asked a question along the lines of "how do I design a Question & Answer website for programmers that's extraordinarily frustrating to use, in the same way as experts-exchange?"

Comment: @Rob ahhhmmm you used the hyphen word :) (what, you don't like finding your question on google and having to pay to subscribe so you can see the answer? )

Comment: @Rob I will try to ask it again on SO

Comment: @Earlz, Not to mention the fact that I find scrolling through screen after screen of "nothing" to get to the "hidden" answers at the bottom of the page rather annoying. Thankfully I don't have to do that anymore ;)

Comment: @Omu: Please see the link I posted above before asking a new question.

Comment: @Jon Seigel if you meant the Captcha than I wasn't interested about that, I wanted to know how to know when some users do to many requests, acts like robot, stuff like that

Comment: @Omu, please don't repost. This should be migrated back to SO

Comment: @Omu: That's fine, but please make your question clear about what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathan Koop is it possible to migrate it back ?

Comment: @Omu, I've flagged it for moderator attention.. I don't believe there is a "belongs on stackoverflow" close reason on Meta though, so it will require a mod.

Comment: What's really telling about this question is ... Not one of the answers is specifically *about* Stackoverflow, thus proving the error in moving this question to meta.

Comment: I've reopened the question, and made it less about Stack Overflow in particular - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380636/how-to-implement-are-you-a-human-feature

Comment: I had also flagged for mod attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Now all this question needs is to be moved *back* to stackoverflow!**

It's almost certainly a heuristic that tries to "guess" that a user is some form of automated process, rather than a person, for example:

- More than "x" requests to do the same thing in a row
- More than "x" actions in a "y" period of time

Ordinarily the "x" and "y" values would be formulated to be ones that it would be unlikely for a "real person" to do, like:

- Editing the same answer 5 times in a row
- Downvoting 10 questions within 1 minute

Once you've got your set of rules, you can then implement some code that checks them at the start of each request, be it in a method that's called in Page_Load, something in your masterpage, something in the asp.net pipeline, that's the easy bit! ;)

Answer (score 3):

just check how many hit / minutes you get from a specific ip or session or whatever and decide what are your preferred threshold and your good to go

Answer (score 2):

At a guess...

Write a HTTP handler that records requests and store them in session.

When a new request comes in, check to see how many requests are stored (and expire old ones).

If the amount of requests in the past few minutes exceeds a given threshold, redirect the user.

If you're doing this in ASP.NET webforms, you could do this check on the site master page, ( or write a `IHttpHandler`).

If you're using an MVC framework, you could write a base controller that does this check for every action.

With rails, you could write a `before_request` filter.

With asp.net MVC, you could write a `[ActionFilterAttribute]` attribute

Answer (score 1):

I'd also check the user agent header of the request - if it doesn't look like a popular browser (or is empty) then throw the "are you a human?" page.

Comment: oh great, guess I can't use lynx!